# Why is $R/I$ cyclic?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, injective-module

The question is in the title, in Rotman's "An introduction to homological algebra", page 125 is the next proposition:

[image]

After the diagram, it says that $R/I$ is cyclic, why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it is generated by $1+I$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it, why?

Comment: @Jotabeta "cyclic" means that it is generated as an $R$-module by a single element. if $r+I\in R/I$ is arbitrary, then $r+I=r\cdot(1+I)$, so indeed all of $R/I$ is in the $R$-submodule generated by $1+I$